# How to place the schema in a JSON file and read the JSON file in Tests of postman?

Tags: json, file, testing, postman, schema

```
const schema = {
    '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
    'title': 'login api',
    'description': 'login response json data verify',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'errno': {
            'type': 'integer',
            'description': 'error code'
        },
        'errmsg': {
            'type': 'string',
            'description': 'message'
        },
        'data': {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'countryAbbr': { 'type': 'string' },
                'countryCode': { 'type': 'string' },
                'email': {
                    'type': 'string',
                    'format': 'email'
                },
                'region': { 'type': 'string' },
                'shopifyStoreToken': { 'type': 'string' },
                'sid': { 'type': 'string' },
                'tuuaUid': { 'type': 'string' },
                'tuuaUsername': { 'type': 'string' },
                'uid': { 'type': 'string' }
            },
            'required': ['countryAbbr', 'countryCode', 'email', 'region', 'shopifyStoreToken', 'sid', 'tuuaUid', 'tuuaUsername', 'uid']
        }
    },
    'required': [
        'errno',
        'errmsg',
        'data'
    ]
};

pm.test("Response contains valid JSON data", () => {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
});
```

How to place the schema in a JSON file and read the JSON file in the Tests of Postman? then if there are any changes to the schema in the future, just modify the JSON file. If there are multiple interfaces, you only need to manage the JSON file.

The way I came up with is to put the JSON file on the server and use pm.request to return the JSON content. But I still want to use the method of reading local JSON files. After searching online, it seems that Postman does not support this method.

```
[this is request url and body][1]
[this is response][2]
[this is schema script in Tests part 1][3]
```

Comment: Can you show us detail of Postman Call example? It include  URL, Verb, input body and output body.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).